# fetch triggers second time

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

the problem actually started, when template was loaded before fetch was complited. So I had to add

```
 $.when(this.model.fetch()).done(function () {
            that.$el.html(that.template({
                model: that.model.toJSON()
            }));
           that.fjskdflsfk();
           that.sdjfksfj();
        });
```

inside render function.

and now I have to fetch data from another url in some cases( after initialization, so first load goes fine)

```
 this.model.fetch({
        url: getUrl() + changeableUrl,
        success: function () {
            console.log("success");
            that.render();
        },
        error: function (model, response) {
            showMessage("error", response.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Success trigers render, and initial fetch trigers in render, which is unwanted in this case.
Maybe someone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `model.fetch` from your view's 'render'. Instead, have your view listen to the model's `sync` event and react by rendering.

```
// in view:

initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
}
```

If this is the only trigger for calling the view's `render`, it won't be called until the model has data, and you won't get extra `fetch` calls because you can remove that `$.when` stuff from the view's `render`.

Comment: I actually just removed _.when(fetch.done()) from render to initialize.

Comment: Your solution is right, but it woun't help in case, when I need to fetch data from different urls...

Comment: It should work for any URL, as long as it's the same instance of the model class. The model fires a `sync` event when it's done fetching, regardless of the URL.